# Gloss - type depending on more fields

Tags: clojure, protocols

I implementing network protocol in [gloss](https://github.com/ztellman/gloss), which has multiple byte codes for one type. For example **digital message** may have codes in range of 0x90 - 0x9F. Naive function for generating that type can looks like this:

```
(defn digital-message
  [port]
  (bit-or 0x90 port))
```

I would like to create encoders and decoders which looks like that:

**decoder:**

```
(decode-all decoder (to-byte-buffer [0x91 0x05 0x98 0x06])) ; [{:type :digital-message :port 1 :some-data 5}
                                                            ;  {:type :digital-message :port 8 :some-data 6}]
```

**encoder:**

```
(encode encoder {:type :digital-message :port 2 :some-data 5}) ; [0x92 0x05]
```

Unfortunaly, I don't know how to implement it and combine with `gloss/header`.

Thanks for any response.